# Error "No such file or directory" occurs when using thrift C++ to connect HBase

Tags: c++, g++

I want to use C++ language to put rows into the HBase. And I use `thrift-0.9.3` and `HBase 1.0.3`. According to [this guide](http://www.alexbod.com/c-plus-plus-hbase-client/), I have installed and configured the thrift.

But when I run command:

```
g++ -Wall -o hclient main.cpp gen-cpp/Hbase_types.cpp gen-cpp/Hbase_constants.cpp \
    gen-cpp/Hbase.cpp -lthrift
```

It shows under errors (cthbase.cpp is my file):

> ```
> cthbase.cpp:14:38: error: thrift/transport/TSocket.h: No such file or directory
> cthbase.cpp:15:48: error: thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h: No such file or directory
> cthbase.cpp:16:45: error: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h: No such file or directory
> In file included from cthbase.cpp:18:
> ....
> ```

I have copied the gen-cpp and other libs in my project folder, but why it cannot find these header files ?

Comment: where is `thrift` directory relative to where you are running `g++` from? You should add a `-I` flag to specify it's location. Read more [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Comment: Thanks,Steve. I have tried add `-I` flag in my command. It shows that `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lthrift  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` and I can't find `libthrift.so` in `/usr/lib` or other folders. so I suppose if I configured the thrift correctly.

Comment: So now you have told gcc where to find your library headers using -I flag. Next you have to tell it where to find you library binaries with -L flag.

Answer (score 1):

Jacky.

Your message:

> Hi, I am a chinese student and learning thrift C++ for HBase currently
>   . Fortunately I found your tutorial and  I follow your steps of
>   installation .However, the issue happens when I do the compilation .
>   It shows under error:
>                                                                                                                                                                /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lthrift
>       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status It looks like it doesn't have thrift link library and I can't find the file libthrift.so in my
>   /usr/lib even cannot find in my computer. So I want to ask if you can
>   solve this problem.  Thank you very much for your reading and
>   replying.
>       By the way, I also raised the issue at stackoverflow, the description may be more detailed . there is the link :
>   [Error "No such file or directory" occurs when using thrift C++ to connect HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077740/error-no-such-file-or-directory-occurs-when-using-thrift-c-to-connect-hbase)
>
> Best Wishes.

First of all, here is the working example, copy it and try it by yourself:
https://github.com/alexbod/hclient/

In your case it seems that the linker could not find the thrift library (-lthrift).

The easiest way is to reinstall Thrift correctly. Are you using Debian?

**Removing:**

If you haven't deleted source tree from which you installed thrift by ./configure && make && sudo make install then just cd to it and

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Otherwise:

```
git clone <repo>
git checkout <revision you installed>
./configure # if you supplied some additional options to configure while building thrift, add them here too.
sudo make uninstall
```

**Dependies:**

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libevent-dev automake libtool flex bison pkg-config g++ libssl-dev
```

**Installation:**

```
wget http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.2/thrift-0.9.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf thrift-0.9.2.tar.gz
$ cd thrift-0.9.2/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then do steps related with Thrift:

http://www.alexbod.com/c-plus-plus-hbase-client/#starting_thrift

http://www.alexbod.com/c-plus-plus-hbase-client/#gen_cpp

Comment: it is very very kind of you, Alex.BTW, Does the Apache Maven essential for thrift?